# VBA Excel Msgbox If statement for action

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run my msgBox in action
Namely, I would like to remove 2 things after clicking "Yes".

I found some solutions here:

[MsgBox Yes/No Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791310/msgbox-yes-no-excel-vba)

[Excel VBA vbYesNo MsgBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890096/excel-vba-vbyesno-msgbox)

and tried to do something working.
My code looks like this:

```
   Case "Remove"

        MsgBox "Do you want to remove all firestopping elements with their values?", 
        vbQuestion + vbYesNo
        If MsgBox(Question) = vbYes Then
        Sheets("hilti firestopping stores").Range("E5:E17").ClearContents
        Call ActiveShapes

        End If
```

...

```
   Sub Firestopshapes()
   Dim shp As Shape
   Dim Ws As Worksheet

   Set Ws = ActiveSheet
   For Each shp In Ws.Shapes
    If shp.Name = "Firestop" Then
        shp.Delete
    End If
  Next shp
 End Sub
```

The result is shown below:

[image]
I also interchanged the `If MsgBox(Question) = vbYes Then` with `If ans = vbYes Then` but I am getting an error instead.

Is it some way to make this msgbox running?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is clearer:

```
Dim ans as VbMsgBoxResult
ans = MsgBox("Do you want to remove all firestopping elements with their values?", _
    vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

If ans = vbYes Then
     ...
End If
```

Comment: straight and simple